# disable parent page, wordpress navigation

Tags: wordpress, navigation, wordpress-theming, parent

I need to disable parent pages in my wordpress navigation menu. I have found a few plugins that disable click-through, but hover arrow and color change are still present. Looking to simply have the parent page show as text in the menu. Here is the header.php code if needed.

http://pastebin.com/Cd4HWTTV.

Please let me know if other information is needed.

Your help is much appreciated.

- Alex

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this a few times before. If I understand correctly, you have something like an About Us section, but there's no content on the About Us page. You want the link in the header to redirect to the first subpage in that section, the History page for example.

The way I had to deal with this was to make About Us redirect to History using a plugin called Page Links To.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/page-links-to/